# How to open tabs windows in Gnu-screen & execute commands within each one

Tags: gnu-screen

when starts session named any name like this `screen -S name1`

i want to open tabs windows in this screen session like when open tabs in gnome-terminal like this

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "some commands"
```

so how to do this ?

Comment: BOTH ı want to know how to open tabs sımılar to gnome termınal and ı want to execute some command ın ıt after ı open tab  ın run tıme

Comment: So the technique I described below shows the tabs that you're looking for then? Just need a way to run a command in them?

Comment: but actually ı am begınner and ı dont understand what u want me to do exactly ı thought that there ıs syntax to open tabs ın the screen aın wındow but ıt seems that ı wıll add some lınes to some fıle

Comment: ok i get that u want me to copy this and past in this file on my home but what i am asking about is screen -t name gives a title to the screen as i know and also i want to open those tabs in a named session for instance `screen -S name1 --tab -e "some commands"` i hope u get what i am asking about ?

Comment: mmmm those are a pre defined tabs with a certain number this is not what i am asking sir :) i dont know how many tabs i need in the run time what i want is something similar to the gnome terminal command `gnome-terminal --tab -e "commands " --tab -e " commands ` this will open one window of terminal with two tabs for instance i mean :) thank u

Comment: Please see my updates to the answer, I've figured out a way, hopefully that's what you're looking for, LMK.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

### 1. Tabs in screen

You're looking for this to add to your .screenrc file:

```
screen -t tab1
screen -t tab2
```

Here's a nice basic .screenrc to get you started with a status bar etc. **NOTE:** This is typically located in your home directory `/home/<username>/.screenrc`.

```
screen -t validate #rtorrent
screen -t compile #irssi
screen -t bash3
screen -t bash4
screen -t bash5
altscreen on
term screen-256color
bind ',' prev
bind '.' next
#
#change the hardstatus settings to give an window list at the bottom of the
#screen, with the time and date and with the current window highlighted
hardstatus alwayslastline
#hardstatus string '%{= kG}%-Lw%{= kW}%50> %n%f* %t%{= kG}%+Lw%< %{= kG}%-=%c:%s%{-}'
hardstatus string '%{= kG}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{= kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{B} %m-%d %{W}%c %{g}]'
```

#### screenshot

[image: ss of screen session]

### 2. Tabs in screen (with commands run inside)

The example `.screenrc` below will create 2 tabs and run 3 echo commands in each.

```
screen -t tab1                                                                                     
select 0                                                                                           
stuff "echo 'tab1 cmd1'; echo 'tab1 cmd2'; echo 'tab1 cmd3'^M"                                     
screen -t tab2                                                                                     
select 1                                                                                           
stuff "echo 'tab2 cmd1'; echo 'tab2 cmd2'; echo 'tab2 cmd3'^M"                                     

altscreen on                                                                                       
term screen-256color                                                                               
bind ',' prev                                                                                      
bind '.' next                                                                                      
#                                                                                                  
#change the hardstatus settings to give an window list at the bottom of the                        
#screen, with the time and date and with the current window highlighted                            
hardstatus alwayslastline                                                                          
#hardstatus string '%{= kG}%-Lw%{= kW}%50> %n%f* %t%{= kG}%+Lw%< %{= kG}%-=%c:%s%{-}'              
hardstatus string '%{= kG}[ %{G}%H %{g}][%= %{= kw}%?%-Lw%?%{r}(%{W}%n*%f%t%?(%u)%?%{r})%{w}%?%+Lw%?%?%= %{g}][%{B} %m-%d %{W}%c %{g}]'
```

This technique makes use of screen's `select` and `stuff` commands to initially select one of the tabs, and then "stuff" a string into it.

#### screenshot

[image: ss of screen w/ tabs & commands]

### 3. Creating #2 without using a `.screenrc` file

If you're looking for the scenario where you can:

1. create a screen session
2. load it up with tabs
3. have each tab running their own commands
4. not require a `.screenrc` file

Then this is the one for you! Be prepared though. This one can get a little tricky with the command lines.

For starters let's create a screen session:

```
$ screen -AdmS myshell -t tab0 bash
```

The switches `-AdmS` do the following:

*(See the [screen man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) for more details)*

> -A
>
> ```
>     Adapt the sizes of all windows to the size of the  current terminal. 
>     By default, screen tries to restore its old window sizes when
>     attaching to resizable terminals
> ```
>
> -d -m
>
> ```
>     Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but
>     doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.
> ```
>
> -S sessionname
>
> ```
>     When creating a new session, this option can be used to specify a
>     meaningful name for the session. This name identifies the session for
>     "screen -list" and "screen -r" actions. It substitutes the default
>     [tty.host] suffix.
> ```

Now let's start loading it up with tabs + their commands:

```
$ screen -S myshell -X screen -t tab1 vim
$ screen -S myshell -X screen -t tab2 ping www.google.com
$ screen -S myshell -X screen -t tab3 bash
```

These 3 commands will create 3 additional tabs and run vim, ping google, and launch a bash shell. If we list out the screen sessions we'll see the following:

```
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        26642.myshell   (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-root.
```

If we connect to the screen session, **myshell**, and list the tabs that it contains we'll see the following:

```
$ screen -r myshell
```

Hit this key combination: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>

```
Num Name                                                                   Flags

  0 tab0                                                                       $
  1 tab1                                                                       $
  2 tab2                                                                       $
  3 tab3                                                                       $
```

Switching to **tab2**:

```
64 bytes from ord08s08-in-f20.1e100.net (74.125.225.116): icmp_seq=443 ttl=55 time=41.4 ms
64 bytes from ord08s08-in-f20.1e100.net (74.125.225.116): icmp_seq=444 ttl=55 time=33.0 ms
64 bytes from ord08s08-in-f20.1e100.net (74.125.225.116): icmp_seq=445 ttl=55 time=30.1 ms
```

#### screenshot

[image: ss of screen initiated from cli]

The above commands are the basic way to accomplish what the OP was looking for. This of course can be condensed and refined using Bash aliases or even shell scripts, this is merely to demonstrate the capability and show the way!

#### References

- [Screen man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html)

Comment: If I do not miss-read the Q he wants to execute a command upon start of session. Typically `screen "cd /foo/bar/; summon_cthulhu;" <<-- in that screen session`

Comment: You think he means, open a screen with tabs, and run a command inside of one of them?

Comment: Yes. Run some shell command at startup *within* screen, typically as when you log in after boot and get `Last login on ... Welcome to XXX, N new mails....`. At least that is how I read the *heading* of the Q.

Comment: Read his comments on the Q, he wants both.

Comment: well done i would like to vote up too but my minor reputation prevented me :)

Comment: but what is `screen -AdmS`

Comment: See additional details in answer. Not sure if you're familiar but most linux commands have manuals that you can access from a shell. Type the command `man` followed by the name of the tool, so you'd type `man screen`. It will tell you what the switches do if you search through it. I've linked to a web version of screen's man page in my answer as well.

Comment: yes thank u i am reading , i have question about difference between -D & -d what he means by "but doesn't fork a new process. The command exits if the session terminates." does in -d if the screen session is closed the running commands or scripts depending on it will still run ? ! or i misunderstand ?

Comment: `-D` is a power detach, so if you run the command `screen -DmS blah` you'll notice that it doesn't detach from the terminal. If you `screen -r blah`into it and type exit in the shell, it will then close. The `-d` on the other hand will detach when you run `screen -dmS blah`. You have to be careful with the terminology. If I understand you correctly, yes, with a `-d`, if you disconnect from it (Ctrl+A d), everything inside will remain and you can reconnect. Does that help? If you have questions about screen you can ask those as separate questions.

Comment: yes it helps and i appreciate it :)

Comment: a big thank @slm for such an extensive explaination with plenty of useful examples.

Answer (score 0):

a small addition to the answer.
stuff is first echoing the command, then it's putting it on the command line, and then executes it if the \n or ^M ends the line.

since the echo annoyed me, i've chained \nclear\n as the last command, so the screen window starts clean.